# Keychain on cygwin asking for passphrase every time a new console gets opened

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, cygwin, keychain

So when you have keychain (http://www.funtoo.org/Keychain) natively on Ubuntu, you only have to enter the key passphrases once per session, but when you're using it on cygwin, it asks for the passphrase every time I open up a new cygwin window, because apparently it treats it as a new session?

So how do I go about fixing this?

Comment: Have you tried running cygserver ?

Comment: Didn't even know about its existence before you mentioned it. I tried it out, but there's not much info about it online, is there something specific I need to configure for keychain to work with it?

Comment: Do you get the "* Warning: Can't determine fingerprint from the following line, falling back to filename" message?

Answer (score 4):

The keychain supplied by Cygwin is outdated.
It lacks support for OpenSSH 6.8-style keys.

If you get the error message "**Warning: can't determine fingerprint from the following line, falling back to filename**",

As hinted in the [Arch forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=194978), add these lines near line 817 in `/usr/bin/keychain`:

```
        *\ @(SHA256|MD5):[0-9a-zA-Z\+\/=]*)
            # The new OpenSSH 6.8+ format,
            #   1024 SHA256:mVPwvezndPv/ARoIadVY98vAC0g+P/5633yTC4d/wXE /home/barney/.ssh/id_dsa (DSA)
            echo "$ef_line" | cut -f2 -d' '
            ;;
```

and this near line 17:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

And it should start functioning as expected again.

Comment: ugh... this worked for me. Thank you!  How has this not been resolved in ~2 years?

Comment: @Erik The [listed Cygwin maintainer](https://www.cygwin.com/packages/summary/keychain.html) dropped off the development lists years ago, and his packages are more or less abandoned since then.  Replacement maintainers have been stepping up since then, to scratch specific itches.  I don't know enough about Cygwin development to guess at how easy or hard it might be if you wanted to take over this package; in theory it's just packaging the upstream script from github.